# Emitting value from VUE 3 setup() listener

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, hello.js

I have a listener on setup() lifecycle method

```
setup() {
    const showLogout = ref(false)
    hello.on('auth.login', function(auth) {
               this.$emit("auth", auth);
            })
    return { showLogout, hello }
  }
```

How to can I get this emit event inside parent component. It is working when I put emit code into normal method, but when it's inside the listener here it's not working.

Any other place I could put this listener into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setup(props,context) {
    const showLogout = ref(false)
    hello.on('auth.login', function(auth) {
               context.emit("auth", auth);
            })
    return { showLogout, hello }
  }
```

OR

```
setup(props,{emit}) {
    const showLogout = ref(false)
    hello.on('auth.login', function(auth) {
             emit("auth", auth);
            })
    return { showLogout, hello }
  }
```

you need to use emit this way

```
<component @authFunction='auth'/>
```

Comment: Thanks, slowly starting to get VUE 3

Comment: your welcome. I had this problem a month ago. that's ok